# Check Email's Bounce Rate ? like what neverbounce do?

Tags: php, validation, email, dns, email-bounces

I wrote PHP script that validates email with smtp check and mx record check.
its able to give weither email is valid or not but 
i want to add functionality of explaining bounce rate of email.
I see similar platform like neverbounce doing this.

Do i need any kind of AW service? or any kind of special hosting to check bulk emails are spam/bounce or not.

Please Advice 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bounces are not about content, but about quality of subscriptions in yours list. Services like [mailcheck.co](https://mailcheck.co), neverbounce etc will help to avoid non existing mails, hard bounces.
For validating email content and MTA settings you may try [mail-tester.com](https://www.mail-tester.com) 
It will suggest to change email content if it looks suspicious, and will ask for proper mail transfer agent settings, like DKIM, SPF etc.
But in common - it's two different tasks. First one validates your email list, second one validates sender and email.